# How to build Approval WorkFlows for a list SP 2010

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I would like to build a workflow.
    But deciding to use out of the box or SPD.

Content editors would add an item that should go to drafting status (pending) and they would like to probably start the workflow manaully.  This should alert the managers by email and editors should be able to enter the email addresses.
The manager will then approve or reject.  If any of these is done the author should receive an email.

Can this be achieved Out of the box or would I have to use Sharepoint Designer?

I tried using the OTB content approval template but I got the error about the State Service.

Comment: Can you give us an update about that? Did it help? Do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you fix (or at least try to fix) your SharePoint configuration (e.g. State Serivce). After that you might want to re-try using the ootb approval workflow. If you see that it does not match your requirements, you are still free to check SPD.

I think using the SPD because you have technical issues is not the best option.

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box content approval workflow sound like it will meet all of your needs. If you provide more details on the State Service error then we can try and resolve it.